# Python selenium how to print a text in .txt file without brackets?

Tags: python

I want to print the text in test.txt file without brackets
my code is

```
azzurlread = azzurl.readlines()
print(azzurlread)
```

the output

```
['qw3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the way would be :

```
with open('sometext.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

also keep in mind that, `readlines()`

> to read the text file and returns the file contents as a list of
> strings:

```
azzurlread = azzurl.readlines()
for line in azzurlread:
    print(line)
```

Comment: If azzurl is a file handle then the output (with square brackets) must be what's in the file! Just because the output looks like a normal representation of a list doesn't mean that that's what it is

Answer (score 1):

It's returning an array with one element.
Try

```
print(azzurlread[0])
```

and it may work

Comment: Yes, this only work for the file in the example, which apparently has a single line. Other answers are better responses.

Comment: OP says in his first sentence "I want to print the text in test.txt file"

Comment: Man please go read about the return of readlines. It does returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
azzurlread = azzurl.readlines()
for el in azzurlread:
    print(el)
```

This should work not only for this specific case with 1 text element only

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using a for loop

```
for line in azzurlread:
    print(line)
    # What to do with line
```